# DevOps pipeline retryCountOnTaskFailure - successful retry but pipeline still reoprts failure

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have an Azure DevOps build pipeline task with a `retryCountOnTaskFailure` set to 3.

In the event of a task failure but successful retry, the pipeline's Job status is still being set to "Failed", despite everything actually succeeding eventually.

Is there a way to make the job status "Success" in this situation, I can't see anything obvious in the documentation.